# SignatureDoesNotMatch error when posting to AWS S3 presign url

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kotlin, pre-signed-url

Really struggling with this one, so any help would be great!

So I am attempting to upload a pdf file to Amazon S3 directly from the browser using presigned urls.

I generate the url on a server using the AWS Java SDK (code written in Kotlin), like this:

```
    val objectKey = StringBuilder().append("xxx").append("/").append("file1.pdf").toString()

    val expiration = java.util.Date()
    var msec = expiration.time
    msec += (1000 * 60).toLong() // Add 1 minute. This means that the url expires in 1 minute.
    expiration.time = msec

    String bucketName = "test"

    val responseHeaders = ResponseHeaderOverrides().withContentType("multipart/form-data")

    val generatePresignedUrlRequest = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey)
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.method = HttpMethod.POST
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.responseHeaders = responseHeaders
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.expiration = expiration

    return s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest)
```

This url is then returned to the browser code, which is using Angular.
I then used the following typescript code to upload the file directly:

```
returnPresignUrl() {
   return this.http.get(this.attachmentUploadUrl, this.httpOptions);
```

}

```
   uploadFiletoS3(file, filetype) {
       let presignURL;
       const data = file;
       const fileHeaders = {
           headers: new HttpHeaders({
               'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
           })
       };
       this.returnPresignUrl().subscribe(url => {
           presignURL = url;
           this.http.post(presignURL, data, 
fileHeaders).subscribe((res) => {
               console.log('File uploaded', res);
           }, (error) => { console.log('Error uploading File', error); 
});
       }, (error) => { console.log('Error getting a preasign URL: ', 
error); });
   }
```

But I get the following error response:

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
    The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you 
provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
```

Any ideas?

I am specifying the content type header in the presign url and then also setting it in the post request to the url, so I can't see how there would be a header mismatch (an error that seems to cause the problem that I am seeing).

Is there anything special about post requests?
Is the content type correct for uploading pdf files to S3?

Any insight would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Can you check your access key and secret key? You get this error when your keys are invalid too.

Comment: The Java SDK indicates that you should use setMethod(HttpMethod method) and the supported methods are GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD. Use PUT. Also, generally you should probably use the setter methods like setResponseHeaders().

Comment: When I change it to PUT, I get an Access Denied error. Any ideas? The access key and secret key should not come into it as the whole point of using presign urls is that we don't need to and store security credentials in the browser.

Comment: Also, this is Kotlin code remember so just referencing the field directly and setting it is the same as calling a set() method

Comment: OK, so now that you are getting AccessDenied, you are past the initial problem. Did your pre-signed URL expire? Is the client time-synced?

Comment: Note that a signed `POST` request does **not** use a pre-signed URL.  It uses a policy document and signature inside an HTML form.

Comment: yep working now, problem was that the lambda that was generating the url did not have the s3 putObject permission.

Answer (score 1):

Use:
`generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType("application/octet-stream");`

instead of:
 `multipart/form-data`.

Here my method for generating the PreSigned URL:

```
public GeneratePresignedUrlRequest getGeneratePresignedUrlRequest(String tempBucketName,String objectKey){
    Date expirationTime = getExpirationTime();
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(tempBucketName, objectKey);
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expirationTime);
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    return generatePresignedUrlRequest;
}
```

When you make call put call to upload the file you should use the same Content-Type.